# Put in evidence and return 1 if already fully factorised

Tags: factorization

Does anyone have a clever idea how to get the overall factor in front of a polynomial or just return 1 if everything is already put in evidence ?

Here is an example with a dummy `GetFactor` function:

```
GetFactor[(2+2u),u]
```

would return: `{2,(1+u)}` while

```
GetFactor[(1+u),u]
```

would return: `{1,(1+u)}`

I could manage doing the first case based on level detection but can't figure out how to do the second case.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What would you want from `GetFactor[(3 +2 u),u]`?  And why do you include the `u` after the comma?

Comment: I think your question is under-specified.  State what you seek for these functions:  $(2 + 3u)$, $(2 + 2 u + 3 u^2)$.

Comment: Look at [`FactorTerms`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTerms) and [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList)

Comment: GetFactor[poly_,var_]:=Module[{f=GCD@@CoefficientList[poly,var]},{f,Expand[poly/f]}]

Comment: @Bill, awesome, thanks !